# How to use "$ref" reference and declare components from Swagger in API platform?

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

We can [define components in Swagger](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/):

```
components:
  schemas:
    User:
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
        name:
          type: string
```

And use this component later:

```
responses:
  '200':
    description: The response
    schema: 
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/User'
```

I want to use this in order to avoid duplicating content.

---

I try to use this syntax in API Platform:

```
components:
    schemas:
        Part:
            description: Array of Part
            type: array
            items:
                type: object
                properties:
                    name:
                        type: string

App\Entity\Item:
    collectionOperations:
        post:
            method: 'POST'
            swagger_context:
                parameters:
                    - name: body
                      description: Item data
                      in: body
                      schema:
                          type: object
                          properties:
                              name:
                                  description: Part
                                  type: string
                                  required: true
                              part:
                                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Part'
```

It gives me an error:

> Exception thrown when handling an exception (Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException: Resource "components" not found in . (which is being imported from "/app/config/routes/api_platform.yaml"). Make sure there is a loader supporting the "api_platform" type.)

It looks like the YAML loader doesn't recognize the `components` item.

---

How can I define and use references in API Platform? How can I define a reference and use it in several YAML files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that like this.

The `components` key belongs to the Swagger/OpenAPI format, not to the API Platform configuration (mapping) format. Both API Platform configuration files and Swagger definitions can be written in YAML, but they are not related.

So, as the error message describes, Swagger `components` cannot be injected in API Platform's configuration files directly, as you try to do.

API Platform's configuration does allow allows to inject some context in the generated Swagger file using the `swagger_context` key, but you cannot write random Swagger definitions (such as your `component` key) outside of this structure.

To do what you want to achieve the `swagger_context` key will not be enough (components must be injected at the root of the Swagger file, and it's not possible with `swagger_context`).

Instead of using this key, you'll have to create a decorator for the Swagger documentation generator, as explained in this documentation entry: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/swagger/#overriding-the-swagger-documentation

Decorator allows to access to the whole Swagger structure, and to modify it. So you'll be able to add your `components` structure.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Do you think that it would be possible to use only YAML? (I mean if a PR could add support of components or if the YAML component will block this behaviour)

Comment: It would be nice indeed! Such PR would be very welcome.

Comment: @KévinDunglas Where can I find an example with a Post action using this decorator approach? I want to show the example body request but I cant seem to make it right. I am trying to insert a custom route (no entity related) in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

It possible ... See [How can I annotate my attribute which is Value Object in order that API Platform would generate its fields for swagger documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56275937/how-can-i-annotate-my-attribute-which-is-value-object-in-order-that-api-platform)

In my exemple, I have the entity Checker, I created two groups :

```
 * @ApiResource(
 *     attributes={
 *          "normalization_context"={"groups"={"read"}},
 *          "denormalization_context"={"groups"={"write"}},
 *     },
```

Then in the swagger_context responses :

```
 *                  "responses" = {
 *                      "201" = {
 *                          "description" = "....",
 *                          "schema" =  {
 *                              "type" = "object",
 *                              "properties" = {
 *                                   "myresult" = {
 *                                      "$ref"="#/definitions/Checker-read"
 *                                   }
```