# How can I annotate my attribute which is Value Object in order that API Platform would generate its fields for swagger documentation?

Tags: php, api, symfony, annotations, api-platform.com

I have an Entity called `Station`.

This entity has a property called `attributes` which is `StationAttributes` value object.

I try to set the property to be `StationAttributes`:

```
/**
* @var StationAttributes
* @ORM\Column(name="attributes", type="station_attributes", nullable=true)
*/
private $attributes;
```

However, the API Platform generates `Station` model that looks like this:

```
{
...
"attributes": "string"
}
```

I want it to be like this:

```
{
...
"attributes": {
    "field": true,
    "field2": "value2",
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went ahead and registered `StationAttributes` as ApiResource/Model and then I've added swagger context to attributes property.

```
/**
 * @var StationAttributes
 *
 * @ApiProperty(
 *     attributes={
 *         "swagger_context"={
 *              "$ref"="#/definitions/StationAttributes"
 *          }
 *     }
 * )
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="attributes", type="station_attributes", nullable=true)
 */
private $attributes;
```